# Responsive Angled CSS Triangles with Percentages

Tags: css, responsive

So I've got an odd responsive design - I'm trying to recreate 2 triangles (white & pink) via CSS that overlay a photo without having to use an image. See photo:
[Responsive/Percentage CSS triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq167.png)

So far, I've got a pretty good idea of how to create the white triangle that overlays the photo and blends in with the background.. but the pink triangle is where i'm stuck and not sure how to program it.

```css
#triangleWrapper {
  background-color: red;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.triangle {
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, white 50%, transparent 50%);
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangleWrapper">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use borders to create triangles. Border width is what you have to play with to make the size how you want it (I just went with full-screen width).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #333;
}

.overlay {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: calc(50vw/6) 50vw;
  border-color: rgba(237, 75, 98, 0.4) rgba(237, 75, 98, 0.4) #fff #ed4b62;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a responsive example

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #333;
}

.image-tri {
  position: relative;
}

.image-tri .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(237, 75, 98, 0.4) rgba(237, 75, 98, 0.4) #fff #ed4b62;
}

@media (min-width: 80px) {
  .image-tri .overlay {
    border-width: 12.5px 40px;
  }
  .image-tri img {
    width: 80px;
    height: 25px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .image-tri .overlay {
    border-width: 50px 160px;
  }
  .image-tri img {
    width: 320px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
  .image-tri .overlay {
    border-width: 150px 480px;
  }
  .image-tri img {
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image-tri">
  <img src="http://fiatifta.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/rio-de-janeiro-banner.jpg">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.